# "Wheel" event triggers more than once despite using throttle

Tags: javascript, events, throttling

i try to do something like this:

```
function throttle(fn, wait) {
    var time = Date.now();
    return function() {
      if ((time + wait - Date.now()) < 0) {
        fn();
        time = Date.now();
      }
    }
}

function callback() {
    //something
}

something.addEventListener("wheel", throttle(callback, 500));
```

When I use mousewheel it seems to work nice and triggers only once. The issue is when I use Macbook's touchpad this event triggers (depending on swipe's length) 1, 2 or 3 times at once. What's a problem?

Comment: By the sounds of it, you want this event to fire only once? ....

Comment: Yes, once every timespan. The bigger issue is why touchpad triggers "wheel" event more than 1 times at once.

Comment: ... Have you thought about trying to target the scroll event & alter your 'throttle' logic? I'm sorry, I'm not sure of what you're trying to achieve, at least not confident enough to provide an answer.

Comment: Another quick question, are you familiar with [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, the problem is that when you "wheel" with a touchpad, you trigger the wheel event **a lot**, especially a lot of very small values.

For example, if you try to scroll this page with a touchpad, you will notice the smoothness of the scroll. That's because many events are fired with a degressive value.

A throttle is a good start but not enough. An upgrade would be to dismiss wheel events with a very small delta value, like this:

```
function throttle(fn, wait) {
    var time = Date.now();

    return function(event) {
      // we dismiss every wheel event with deltaY less than 4
      if (Math.abs(event.deltaY) < 4) return

      if ((time + wait - Date.now()) < 0) {
        fn(event);
        time = Date.now();
      }
    }
}

function callback(event) {
    // something
}

something.addEventListener("wheel", throttle(callback, 500));
```

It won't be "perfect" but close.

If you want a perfect result, some advanced maths is necessary. And when I mean advanced, I mean I would myself need one week or two full-time to implement it cleanly across all devices.

If you want to control the wheel to scroll from a screen A to a screen B, you should check out the [css scroll snapping property](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/).